# AJAX infinite scroll $(window).scroll(function() { not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am trying to incorporate infinite scroll in my rails application, but with limited success. I have pagination working right now with the rails gem `will_paginate`, but my script for infinite scroll is not getting past `$(window).scroll(function() {` function.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    console.log('test');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log('test2');
        var url = $('.pagination span.next').children().attr('href');
        if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
            $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");
            return $.getScript(url);
        }
    });
});
```

The first test is passing, but the script does not make it to the second test when I inspect the element in Chrome. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

Put $(window).scroll() out side of ready() as

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log('test2');
        var url = $('.pagination span.next').children().attr('href');
        if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
            $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");
            return $.getScript(url);
        }
    });
```